# Typo causing unable to connect to MongoDB running in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I run MongoDB in a docker container like this

`docker run --name mongo -d -p 27017:27107 mongo`

Check with `docker ps` shows

`77f1a11295c3   mongo                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27017->27107/tcp   mongo`

so it's running with the port mapped correctly.

When I try to setup a connection via Intellij

[image: Intellij]

it fails with

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}].
```

When I try to connect to connect from a golang web server

clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

I get this error and it shuts down the web server:

```
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: connection(localhost:27017[-64]) incomplete read of message header: read tcp 127.0.0.1:40700->127.0.0.1:27017: read: connection reset by peer }, ] }
```

Is this a bug in the MongoDB docker image, or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo mistake while creating a container. `27017 and 27107`

`docker run --name mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongo`

This is clearly visible in docker ps command.

Can you try and see if it solves the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As @fly2matrix said you have a typo, and I believe you have another issue:

1. you forward the ports **27017:27107**, in which the container port is incorrect. Check **27107** instead of **27017**
2. It seems you're connecting to **localhost** instead of **mongo** as I see the phrase **localhost** in your code.